# Cannot convert void to list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I am trying to write my first c# program and I can't keep getting the error below. Can someone explain why I am getting this error? Everything has a type when it is declared, where is the void coming from? I am writing the code on https://repl.it/languages/csharp if it is important.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
  List<string> mylist = new List<string>() { "2","1","2","3","3","4" };

  mylist=mylist.Sort();

  foreach(var item in mylist)
  {
      Console.Write(item.ToString());
  }
  }
}
```

Error:

> ```
> Cannot implicitly convert type `void' to `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
> ```

Comment: `Sort()` is in-place. No need to assign the result.

Comment: Most stuff in the framework is mutable, and so methods that change the original object tend to return void rather than the object being mutated.  Strings are a noted exception to this.

Comment: @Will It's more accurate to call arrays the exception. Strings are included in that because they use an array as the underlying data type.

Comment: @Abion47 Meh, you're splitting hairs.  You can mutate an array, but you can't directly change its length.  But that's not **the** reason why Strings are immutable, that decision was much more involved than an implementation detail of the array type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`List<T>.Sort` returns `void` as it actually modifies the `List` it is called on (it doesn't return a new collection). Hence assigning the method's return value to a `List` is a compile error.

If you want a sort that does not modify the underlying collection, consider using `OrderBy` and `ToList` if you want to eager-enumerate the result.

Answer (score 3):

`mylist.Sort();`  doesn't return `List`, it returns `void`, you shouldn't assign it to a list.
After calling `Sort` your  entire list  is already sotred.